# Webpack 2 jQuery

Tags: jquery, webpack

Как подключить в webpack 2 jquery.

в файле index.html подключается 2 скрипта + идет инициализация плагина

```
<script src="/dist/js/common.js"></script>
<script src="/dist/js/plugin.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
   $('div').plugin();
});
</script>
```

в webpacke

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
   $: 'jquery',
   "window.jQuery": 'jquery',
   jQuery: 'jquery'
})
```

В common js

```
import jQuery from 'jquery';

window.JQuery = jQuery;
window.$ = jQuery;
```

И все равно на строчке в index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
   $('div').plugin();
})
</script>
```

**jQuery is not defined**

Нужно чтобы jquery был виден по всему проекту